# R glm for censored data

Tags: r, distribution, glm, normal-distribution

I want to know if there is a significant difference in a blood biomarker concentration between 2 populations (population 1 = healthy individuals - population 2 = sick individuals). I need to control for the factor 'region'.

My issue is that the distribution of population 2 is not normal (data are censored following the upper detection limit by the lab device) as shown on these plots:

[image]

With a normal distribution I would use this model in R:

```
m <- glm(blood.biomarker ~ status + region + status*region, data=f, family="gausian") # status = healthy or sick
summary(m)
emmeans(m, list(pairwise ~ status), adjust = "tukey")
```

I am a bit confused regarding the model or the glm family I should use in this case.

I also have a similar situation but with 3 groups (1 group has a normal distribution and 2 groups have a censored distribution). How to deal with this?

Comment: Hello Falco, could you provide sample of your data ?

Comment: There was an attempt to migrate your question to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions as it needs stats advice, rather than a programming question. For some reason, the migration was rejected so it may be worth just reposting the question yourself at the stats site.

Comment: ... never mind, I see that you had also asked on the stats site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605600/r-glm-for-censored-data . This is probably why the migration was rejected. (ps it is good form to either only post on one site or at least acknowledge the other post)